# How to call a method using reflection

Tags: c#

How do i use reflection to call this method.

```
using System.Reflection

public static string NotSoObvius<V>(V show) where V : class
    {
        return string.Format("This is it", show);
    }
```

Comment: We cannot see the class or struct in which the method is a member. But otherwise something like `var res = (string)typeof(Xxx).GetMethod("NotSoObvius").MakeGenericMethod(show.GetType()).Invoke(null, new[] { show, })` should be fine.

Comment: noted thank you, but i am not understanding a little

Answer (score -1):

You should try something like this:

```
Type myType = Type.GetType("MyClass");
MethodInfo notSoObviusInfo = myType.GetMethod("NotSoObvius");
Type[] types = new Type[]{typeof(YourDesiredTypeHere)};
notSoObviusInfo = notSoObviusInfo.MakeGenericMethod(types);
string myReturn = (string)notSoObviusInfo.Invoke(null, new[]{new YourDesiredTypeHere()});
```

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But `V` was not an actual type, it was a type argument to the method. So `V` is not in scope above. And you want to use `MakeGenericType` to specify what the type argument should be (see my comment to the question). And a `static` method does not need a "this" target (your `magicClassObject`). So your answer has several issues.

Comment: You right. I just fixed my answer following MSDN tutorial:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx
"If a constructor is static, this argument must be null or an instance of the class that defines the constructor."

Comment: Answer updated and it is now all functional!